# Preventing Centos user from installing unsigned RPMs

Tags: sudo, rpm, centos8, sudoers, dnf

I have a CentOS 8 system that I want the user to be able to install RPMs. I plan on doing something like the following in the sudoers file:

```
username ALL = NOPASSWD : /usr/bin/dnf
```

However, obviously this has security implications. I would like to configure dnf to only allow rpm installs that are signed with my key. Therefore the user can use dnf to install only the RPMs I provide.

Is this possible? If so, Is there a dnf flag that could ignore this setting (and therefore defeat this purpose). I'm looking in the dnf configuration but I can't tell if what I am reading will accomplish what I want.

My fallback to to create a standalone program to do this, and only allow sudo access to that program, but I would prefer to not add another application to the system.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all but your GPG keys from the system (`rpm -qa |grep pubkey`) and in dnf.conf set to true `gpgcheck`, `localpkg_gpgcheck` and set `gpgkey` to your key.
This will work for most casual users.

As bonus I will provide the answer for your users on how to work around it:

- pass `--nogpgcheck` to dnf
- use `--setopt` to disable all the settings above
- simple answer yes, when DNF prompts you to install a new GPG key